# What is shared with my Google+ circles?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-circles

I like to organise things a little bit too much. When Google+ was launched I got a little bit obsessed with the circles feature, and I have 50+ circles right now. Sharing content on Google+ is more about collections now (of which I have less) and I would like to delete as many circles as possible. But I don't want to delete circles with which I already shared something, because that content may get unavailable completely this way.

The question is, how can I tell which circle has some content that is shared with that circle?